# what is this bash alternative to this python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

what is the bash alternative to this python

```
with open("file", 'x') as f: #open file
    for line in f.readlines():#for each line in file
       word = line.split("/") #turn line into the array word
       print(word) #
```

I have thought about

```
for i in file
do
IFS'/' var1 var2
echo $var2
done
```

but I am very inexperienced in bash scripting

Comment: Dare I ask *why* you'd want to move from a relative safe programming language to shell scripting, which exists to silently ignore errors and do insane things?

Comment: @shadowRanger for what im trying to do i need to download html and python cant do that

Comment: how do you know Python cannot download HTML?

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan I don't believe the base python can download it by itself without the use of user-created libraries or running commands like wget or curl. if there is a way to what was mentioned without using wget or user-created libraries then I have not come across it

Comment: @NimballDimpall see my answer

Comment: I suggest that you run your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch the most obvious errors. BTW, reading an introductory tutorial on bash would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned Python is not able to download HTML without using external library, but this sample is only using internal library.

```
$ cat test.py
import urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://google.com")

print(data.read())
```

Output

```
$ python3 test.py
b'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-MY"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="J+dyoOcziE1OqkDIbQfsNQ==">(function(){window.google={kEI:\'WI0pYobbAuvd2roPnPGw4AY\',kEXPI:\'0,1302536,56873,6058,207,4804,2316,383,246,5,1353,4014,1237,1122516,1197754,647,22,380067,16115,28684,17572,4859,1361,9291,3028,17580,4020,978,13228,3847,4192,6430,14762,7979,5081,1593,1279,2451,291,149,1103,840,1983,214,4100,3514,606,2023,2297,14670,3227,2845,7,17450,8101,8219,1851,1575
```